# how to unzip file with C# console application, dotnetzip library

Tags: c#, sftp

i've to unzip the specific file to a specific folder

Im using C# visual studio express 2010 and dotnetzip library to zip

```
//take the zip file from sftp
Console.WriteLine("Mendownload File va_txn dari KPFS");
            Console.WriteLine("===================================");
            string remoteDirectory = "/va/";

            using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
            {
                try
                {
                    sftp.Connect();
                    var fileIn = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);
                    foreach (var file in fileIn)
                    {
                        if (!file.Name.Equals(".") && !file.Name.Equals("..") && file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine("File ditemukan, selesai dikompress");

                            //code to download file
                            using (Stream file1 = File.Create(@"C:\Users\u532246\Desktop\VA\" + file.Name))
                            {
                                sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + file.Name, file1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                sftp.Disconnect();
            }

            //Unzip file
            string pathzip = @"C:\Users\Desktop\VA\va_for_copartner_daily.zip";
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.ExtractAll(pathzip);
            }
```

The problem is , when the unzip file code running, the  unzipped file nowhere found, i dont know what im missing or wrong , maybe someone can help me fix my code ?

Comment: Has nothing to do with your actual question, but an empty catch block is bad programming style - at least log the exception somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually reading the zip file, you're just extracting an empty archive since you've not given a parameter to the `ZipFile` constructor.

This should do it:

```
//Unzip file
string pathzip = @"C:\Users\Desktop\VA\va_for_copartner_daily.zip";
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile.Read(pathzip))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(@"C:\Users\Desktop\VA\SomeOtherFolder");
}
```

Comment: oh my fault there , already correct the code and it works ! thankyouuu